# jquery ajax not working after postback

Tags: asp.net, jquery

Hi Here is the scenario:

I have an asp:Button on the page, and on clicking on the button, it verifies certain logic and displays a details block. This details block has bunch of web user controls, which make their own jquery ajax calls and load different controls using jquery templating plugin.

The details panel is inside a asp:Placeholder and i set visible property to true on postback.

The details panel was working fine earlier since i did not had a button click which does a postback to load the details panel. It was displayed by default earlier. How do i get my web user controls make an ajax call after the postback completes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.  I just added a hidden field on the page, and on postback i filled it with some value. On jquery instead of calling the functions directly on document ready, i checked what is the value set to the hidden field. This resolved the issue.